# Kivy how to do placement of a Label's child

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I try to implement a widget, composed of a label as master and a button as it's switchable child, by inheriting from kivymd HoverBehavior. 
None of my trials to steer placement of the widget itself   and it's child inside was successful.
 I tested BoxLayout, FloatLayout, GridLayout and AnchorLayout as widget's base layout. The results were not satisfying.
Is mixing kivy and kivymd.uix.behaviors, the way I'm doing, allowed or is it the wrong approach?

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.properties import ColorProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex as custom_rgba

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import HoverBehavior


kv = """
#: import custom_rgba kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex


<Label_withBorder>:
    border_width: dp(2)
    border_color: custom_rgba('#bdc3c8')
    font_size: dp(15)
    background_color: custom_rgba('#ffffff')
    color: self.text_color
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.border_color if root.border_width > 0 else root.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
        Color:
            rgba: root.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.width - 2 * root.border_width, self.height - 2 * root.border_width
            pos: int(self.center_x - (self.width - (2 * root.border_width)) / 2.0), int(self.center_y - (self.height - 2.0 * root.border_width) / 2.0)


<Custom_HeaderLabel_withBorder>:
    background_color: custom_rgba('#7a4e2a')
    color: custom_rgba('#393939')

<Hover_HeaderLabel_withBorder>:


<HeaderCell_ToolButton>:
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
    text: "i"
    on_release: root.cell_action()


<Tool_HeaderCell>:


<Example>:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'center'
    Tool_HeaderCell:
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
        text: 'header A'

"""


class Label_withBorder(Label):
    background_color = ColorProperty()
    text_color = ColorProperty(custom_rgba('#000000'))

    border_color = ColorProperty(custom_rgba('#5e5f60'))
    border_width = NumericProperty()
    pass


class Custom_HeaderLabel_withBorder(Label_withBorder):
    pass


class Hover_HeaderLabel_withBorder(Custom_HeaderLabel_withBorder, HoverBehavior):
    pass


class HeaderCell_ToolButton(RelativeLayout, Button):
    header_cell = ObjectProperty()

    def cell_action(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.header_cell.cell_action()


class Tool_HeaderCell(RelativeLayout, Hover_HeaderLabel_withBorder):
    tool = ObjectProperty()
    remove_button_on_leave = BooleanProperty(True)

    def cell_action(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.remove_button_on_leave:
            self.remove_button_on_leave = False
            self.tool.text = 'I will stay'
        else:
            self.remove_button_on_leave = True
            self.tool.text = 'I will disappear'

    def on_enter(self):
        if not self.children:
            self.tool = HeaderCell_ToolButton(header_cell=self, text='press me ...')
            self.add_widget(self.tool)
        pass

    def on_leave(self):
        if self.remove_button_on_leave:
            if self.children:
                for child in self.children:
                    if isinstance(child, Button):
                        self.remove_widget(child)
        pass

    pass


class Example(AnchorLayout):
    pass


class Tool_HeaderCell_App(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return Example()

    pass


Tool_HeaderCell_App().run()
```

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do ?

Comment: The widget should act for example as a datagrid's header cell, with an additional button, added or removed on demand. It is also thinkable to replace the Button by an icon with  ButtonBehavior, showing different symbols.